# I want to display the records of a custom Student object on entering the names of students as input. The records are not showing up on the table

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components

**searchStudentComponent.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon> Custom Search Functionality on
            Student Object in LWC.
        </h3>

        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-input type="search" class="slds-m-bottom_small" label="Search Student Name"
                onchange={searchStudentAction} value={studentName}></lightning-input>
        </p>

        <div class="slds-p-around--medium">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="lwsTablePad">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Father's Name</th>
                    <th>Mother's Name</th>
                </tr>
                <template for:each={studentList} for:item="stuObj" for:index="index">
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={stuObj.Id}>
                        <td>{stuObj.Student_Name__c}</td>
                        <td>{stuObj.Father_Name__c}</td>
                        <td>{stuObj.Mother_Name__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </table>
        </div>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**searchStudentComponent.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getStudents from '@salesforce/apex/SearchStudentController.getStudents';
const DELAY = 100;

export default class SearchStudentComponent extends LightningElement {
    studentName = '';
    studentFatherName = '';
    studentMotherName = '';
    @track studentList = [];
    @wire(getStudents, {
        stuName: '$studentName',
        stuFatherName: '$studentFatherName',
        stuMotherName: '$studentMotherName',
    })
    retrieveStudents({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accountList = data;
        }
        else if (error) {

        }
    }

    searchStudentAction(event) {
        //this.studentName = event.target.value;
        const searchString = event.target.value;
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.studentName = searchString;
        }, DELAY);
    }
}
```

**searchStudentComponent.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**SearchStudentController.cls**

```
public with sharing class SearchStudentController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Student__c> getStudents(String stuName, String stuFatherName, String stuMotherName) {
        String keyNameString = '%' +  stuName + '%';
        return [Select Id, Student_Name__c, Father_Name__c, Mother_Name__c From Student__c Where Student_Name__c like:keyNameString];
    }
}
```

Comment: is your apex class executing the query? is your wire method returning any data? please include debug info.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you're looping over `studentList`, which is defined as an empty array in the JS and never updated, because the wired method sets `accountList`.
So you have to change `retrieveStudents` method to

```js
retrieveStudents({ data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.studentList = data;
    }
}
```

You could also remove the `track` decorator from `studentList` since its value (the reference to an array) will change everytime `retrieveStudents` is called.